# Eval can't access a nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, webforms, eval, repeater

Usually, on a foreach inside the .ascx I access to a nullable DateTime with:

```
<%=item.DataModifica.Value.ToShortDateString() %>
```

but if I tried on a Repeater:

```
<%#Eval("DataModifica.Value.ToShortDateString()").ToString()%>
```

I get an Exception

> *System.DateTime' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'*

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the code like this:

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DataModifica")).ToShortDateString()%>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Markzzz has provided and excellent solution .I assume that your `DataModifica` is a nullable field that's why you are checking its `Value`. when there is a `null` value it cant be converted by `.ToString()` methods . you have to use `Convert` class's method or check your field for null values and do accordingly. Here is an example

```
<%# (Eval("DataModifica") != null ? Eval("DataModifica","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") : "Not Available") %>
```

Comment: Great answer to the question by considering checking for null

Answer (score 0):

Use type DateTime? you can do this:

(Eval("DateCreate") != null && Eval("DateCreate") is DateTime) ? DateTime.Parse(Eval("DateCreate").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "immediate"